# How do I manage Cassandra/Scylla snapshots?

Tags: backup, cassandra, snapshot, scylladb, cql

I am new to Scylla, and I'm looking to setup a proper Backup & Restore solution.

I've just tested running `nodetool snapshot -t my_backup`, and see that what it does is create a snapshot folder caled `my_backup`, inside each keyspace & table folder.

This causes a few limitations in my view:

1. I can't easily save the backups on another server, in case this specific server dies
2. I can't easily restore a backup on another server (e.g. as a daily snapshot for production support purposes/tests)

**How do DBAs normally store backups in another server and restore a whole database into another server ?**

--

Another issue I noticed is that `nodetool listsnapshots` doesn't seem to mention the snapshot creation date in the output.

So I don't seem to be able to find a way to purge old snapshots.

**How do I "delete snapshots older than 10 days" or "keep last 3 backups", for example?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're moving your snapshots to another server or cloud storage (ex: S3 bucket) then removing old snapshots after a certain number of days is a simple matter of running a Linux `find` for each snapshot dir by date, and then an `rm -rf` on each that you want to get rid of.

This question was asked on Stack Overflow a while ago, and the answers are still relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144980/deleting-specific-cassandra-snapshots/31147289#31147289

My answer above contained a script that pretty much did what I described above.

It's also worth checking out [Medusa](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-medusa), which is a Cassandra backup utility.  I'm fairly certain that it has ways of managing old snapshots.